# Multicast with AF_LOCAL or AF_UNIX sockets on Linux?

Tags: linux, sockets, unix, posix, multicast

Is it possible to have multicast communications on a `AF_UNIX` `SOCK_DGRAM` socket on Linux ?

Apparently [a patch was proposed over a decade ago](https://lwn.net/Articles/27001/). However, I cannot find any resource on Internet showing its usage. And the following simple code reports `Operation not supported`.

```
u_int yes = 1;
int fd = socket(AF_LOCAL, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(yes));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The patch you refer to was never applied.

You can't do multicast on AF_UNIX sockets, and at least on linux, SO_REUSEADDR doesn't have any meaning (it's not implemented) for AF_UNIX sockets.